# PostgreSQL: Count Number of Occurrences in Columns

Tags: postgresql, count, duplicates

### BACKGROUND

I have three large tables (employee_info, driver_info, school_info) that I have joined together on common attributes using a series of `LEFT OUTER JOIN` operations. After each join, the resulting number of records increased slightly, indicating that there are duplicate IDs in the data. To try and find all of the duplicates in the IDs, I dumped the ID columns into a temp table like so:

### Original Dump of ID Columns

| first_name | last_name | employee_id | driver_id | school_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mickey | Mouse | 1234 | abcd | wxyz |
| Donald | Duck | 2423 | heca | qwer |
| Mary | Poppins | 1111 | acbe | aaaa |
| Wiley | Cayote | 1234 | strf | aaaa |
| Daffy | Duck | 1256 | acbe | pqrs |
| Bugs | Bunny | 9999 | strf | yxwv |
| Pink | Panther | 2222 | zzzz | zzaa |
| Michael | Archangel | 0000 | rstu | aaaa |

In this overly simplified example, you will see that IDs `1234` (employee_id), `strf` (driver_id), and `aaaa` (school_id) are each duplicated at least once. I would like to add a count column for each of the ID columns, and populate them with the count for each ID used, like so:

### ID Columns with Counts

| first_name | last_name | employee_id | employee_id_count | driver_id | driver_id_count | school_id | school_id_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mickey | Mouse | 1234 | 2 | abcd | 1 | wxyz | 1 |
| Donald | Duck | 2423 | 1 | heca | 1 | qwer | 1 |
| Mary | Poppins | 1111 | 1 | acbe | 1 | aaaa | 3 |
| Wiley | Cayote | 1234 | 2 | strf | 2 | aaaa | 3 |
| Daffy | Duck | 1256 | 1 | acbe | 1 | pqrs | 1 |
| Bugs | Bunny | 9999 | 1 | strf | 2 | yxwv | 1 |
| Pink | Panther | 2222 | 1 | zzzz | 1 | zzaa | 1 |
| Michael | Archangel | 0000 | 1 | rstu | 1 | aaaa | 3 |

You can see that IDs `1234` and `strf` each have 2 in the count, and `aaaa` has 3. After generating this table, my goal is to pull out all records where any of the counts are greater than 1, like so:

### All Records with One or More Duplicate IDs

| first_name | last_name | employee_id | employee_id_count | driver_id | driver_id_count | school_id | school_id_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mickey | Mouse | 1234 | 2 | abcd | 1 | wxyz | 1 |
| Mary | Poppins | 1111 | 1 | acbe | 1 | aaaa | 3 |
| Wiley | Cayote | 1234 | 2 | strf | 2 | aaaa | 3 |
| Bugs | Bunny | 9999 | 1 | strf | 2 | yxwv | 1 |
| Michael | Archangel | 0000 | 1 | rstu | 1 | aaaa | 3 |

### Real World Perspective

In my real-world work, the JOIN'd table contains 100 columns, 15 different ID fields and over 30,000 records, and the final table came out to be 28 more than the original. This may seem like a small amount, but each of the 28 represent a broken link that we must fix.

Is there a simple way to get the counts populated like in the second table above? I have been wrestling with this for hours already, and have not been able to make this work. I tried some aggregate functions, but they cannot be used in table UPDATE operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `COUNT` function, when used as an analytic function, can do what you want here, e.g.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
           COUNT(employee_id) OVER (PARTITION BY employee_id) employee_id_count,
           COUNT(driver_id)   OVER (PARTITION BY driver_id)   driver_id_count,
           COUNT(school_id)   OVER (PARTITION BY school_id)   school_id_count
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE
    employee_id_count > 1
    driver_id_count > 1
    school_id_count > 1;
```

Comment: How can I get this to not match up on NULLs? It is counting NULL values, which is what I do not want/need.

Comment: @MichaelSheaver Just count the columns themselves (I think this is what you want here).

Comment: @Michael Sheaver add a case when statement for your nulls. Case when the id is null, make the column show 0 else count. This could solve your problem.

Comment: @T.kowshikYedida No, that's not necessary, because the `COUNT` function by default already will not count a `NULL` value.  The problem with `COUNT(*)` is that this doesn't apply, because it will always count one for every record.

Comment: What could be the problem asked by OP then, "How can I get this to not match up on NULLs? It is counting NULL values, which is what I do not want/need." I didn't quite get it right, then.